# Excel merge 2 formulas

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

I have two formulas which I would like to merge into one, but dont know how to do it. I need to filter out blank cells and remove duplicates.

Data example:

[image]

The first formula to remove blank spaces is this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$500,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$500<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$500)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Second formula will remove any duplicity.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1,A1,"")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it may be helpful if you post some data example of how this formula works and how you apply it.

Comment: sorry for not providing enough information. Here is a picture of sample data. In column A I have data which include duplicates, I need to be output like shown in column B. Basically trying to replicate remove duplicity function using formula. https://i.imgur.com/0ITFThB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> **Here a solution to the task as I understood it yesterday:**

Remove "blank spaces": `=substitute(A1," ","")`

your countif  `=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1,A1,"")`

Together:
`=substitute(IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1,A1,"")," ",""))`

**Values which differ only by spaces will be displayed as different!**

If you have values which are equal after the substitution (e.g. "b b" and "bb")
then you need two rows and you need to resort after the substitution.
Then there is no way to combine the two formulas without some further work.
(e.g. vba solution: substitute, resort and output).

> **Here's how I would solve it with vba:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub sample_values()
    Range("A1").Value = "Values"
    Range("A2").Value = "2023"
    Range("A3").Value = "2141"
    Range("A4").Value = "2156"
    Range("A5").Value = "2175"
    Range("A6").Value = "2300"
    Range("A7").Value = "23 00"
    Range("A8").Value = "23 0 0  "
    Range("A9").Value = "2181"
    Range("A10").Value = "2188"
    Range("A11").Value = "2204"
    Range("A12").Value = "2207"
    Range("A13").Value = "2211"
    Range("A14").Value = "22 11"
    Range("A15").Value = "2 2 1 1"
    Range("A16").Value = "221  1"
    Range("A17").Value = "221   1"
    Range("A18").Value = "2236"
    Range("A19").Value = "2239"
    Range("A20").Value = "2250"
End Sub

Sub rb_s_ouv()
'remove_blanks_and_sort_and_output_unique_values()

Dim myInput As Range
Dim sortedInput As Range
Dim outputRng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim uniqueCt As Integer
Dim noBlanks_Column As Boolean

lastRow = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Set myInput = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
'Debug.Print myInput.Address

noBlanks_Column = True     'no blanks in an individual column
'noBlanks_Column = False   'no blanks in the original column

'substitute blanks
If noBlanks_Column Then myInput.Offset(-1, 2).Value = "no_blanks"
For Each cell In myInput
    If noBlanks_Column Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Replace(cell.Value, " ", "")
    Else
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, " ", "")
    End If
Next cell

'sort input
If noBlanks_Column Then
    myInput.Offset(0, 2).Sort myInput.Offset(0, 2), xlAscending
    Set sortedInput = myInput.Offset(0, 2)
Else
    myInput.Sort myInput, xlAscending
    Set sortedInput = myInput
End If

'output unique values
sortedInput.Offset(-1, 2).Range("A1").Value = "unique values"
Set outputRng = sortedInput.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1")

uniqueCt = 0
For Each cell In sortedInput
    If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        outputRng.Offset(uniqueCt, 0).Value = cell
        uniqueCt = uniqueCt + 1
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

---

Detail regarding "no blanks" column:

[image]

Comment: if i do this, there will be leftover blank rows?

Comment: Yes! You are right!Please find above a vba solution! You might also use vba for the substitution and a pivot to display the unique values!

Comment: thank you a lot but im not looking for a vba solution tho, i need to be it a formula. Thank you for providing the vba solution.